# Change name of iPhone app... still be able to access UserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have an app out to the world.. let's call it xyzFREE.  Apple no longer allows the name FREE to be in the app name.  So I will change it to xyzLITE.  I create a new Xcode project, and then I change the bundle ID from xyzLITE to xyzFREE, and it updates the version I download from the app store to the new version.  All seems well.

xyzFREE uses UserDefaults to store high scores.  The new version xyzLITE creates its own UserDefaults, so all the high scores are gone.  Is there a way to load the UserDefaults from xyzFREE, so I can convert it and save it in the UserDefaults for xyzLITE?

I have also tried creating a new Version of xyzFREE, changing the name to xyzLITE, but it still does the same thing. It creates its own UserDefaults, so all the high scores are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the display name of your app.

Comment: Yes.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Just to add to the answer.  The only thing that needs to change is the Bundle name in the info.plist.  It was defaulted to $(PRODUCT_NAME) and I changed that to xyzLITE.